# OAuth 2 Provider: client-side popup

Tags: oauth-2.0, window.open

I'm curious how OAuth 2 providers (namely Facebook and Google) implement the client-side flow inside of a popup.  How does the client application receive the access token back from the popup?  I was under the impression that one cannot communicate with another window (created via `window.open`) unless it is of the same origin (which it is not in the case of these OAuth logins).

Thanks!